# AJAX, Javascript Iteration Counter

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Having issues with updating text on my page after every Ajax call.

Looping though an Object to upload to DB, Object could contain 100+ items and during each Ajax call I would like to update text on how many have been successful.

However this does not work. It won't update the text until the loop is complete. Im trying to update "document.getElementById("counter").innerText = "Uploading " + successCount;" after every loop.

Example loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<dataObj.length; i++) {

$.ajax({
                url : 'URL',
                type : 'POST',
                async: false,
                    data: 'data=' + encodeURIComponent(tempObj),
                    dataType:"json",
                    success : function(data) {
                      if(status == '"SUCCESS"'){
                      successCount++;
                      document.getElementById("count").innerText = successCount;
                      }else{
                        alert("error");
                      }
                    },
                    error : function(request,error)
                    {
                      alert("error");
                    }
                  });
}
```

Any ideas on why updating the element won't work during a loop when making Ajax calls?

Comment: Why you are not use async: true?

Answer (score -1):

I think if your ajax call is ok(I pressume it is) it updates. What happens here is due to the loop. you can't see the changes, only the last change. Btw, you can `console.log()` on success method inside `status=='SUCCESS'` and see how many time it changes.

*Add. it is not good to have ajax call inside loop and let it happen n times like you did here. You need to submit all data altogether or rethink for alternative about this solution.*